# Apex class changes in managed package

Tags: salesforce

I have an apex class that is inside my managed package which is build inside my base Devloper edition Account.the package is already uploaded as managed package.now i need to modify my apex class & the changes which i have made must be reflected in managed package but it is not happening. can any one tell me what can be the way.THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the class in you dev org you still need to deploy, sounds like you are missing it.

Comment: Can you please tell me How to deploy the class ?

Comment: Setup->Create->Package click on your package Click Add button Choose Apex Class in Component Type Select the checkbox near your class click Add To Package And proceed to upload the new Package.

Comment: So now all you need to do is deploy the package to your destination org. After creating a package you are getting a url enter this url in your browser when logged in your destination org.